# Do you have any credits listed on IMDB?

Tags: design, editing, community, imdb

I would like to watch films where the sound design/editing has been done by our community here at social sound design. So if you have some credits that you recommend I watch I would be glad to do so.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I look forward to trying to get a copy of the movies provided. 

Answer (score 2):

here is mine.

http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1269512/

Answer (score 2):

There are only a few movies that I have worked on that I always recommend to people, not because I contributed to them or because the sound effects were super-cool, but because they are **excellent films**, period. One is [Road To Perdition](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0257044/), another is [Letters From Iwo Jima](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0498380/).

Entire imdb list is [here](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0421174/).

Answer (score 1):

I have a single listing on mine... I was also the sound designer, but the director didn't understand what that meant.

http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3860067/

I'll try to find a link for the video.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0695670

my personal favourites:

- Boy
- The Warrior's Way
- 30 Days of Night
- The World's Fastest Indian
- The Frighteners

Comment: I found The world's fastest Indian on Netflix instant so I will watch it today.

Comment: I'm watching it right now... Great sound, great story.

Comment: theres an old post about sound for Fastest Indian here:

http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/worlds-fastest-indian


Answer (score 1):

Here's mine also:[link text](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2049839/)

Answer (score 1):

I did the score and contributed to the sound design for this short film currently going through festivals. I also did the score and sound design for the trailer here:

This Way Up
http://www.imdb.com/video/wab/vi2140014105/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3528749/

Office of the Dead is the only feature I've designed that has gotten a distribution deal...currently available on Amazon.com, but the publisher was more interested in getting it out than fixing a few niggling problems I found out about too late...the joys of independent, ultra-low budget filmmaking ;-)

The Mountain Crumbles is hitting several festivals currently and is probably my favorite piece I have designed to date. I was also the editor and designer for A Yeti in the City http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1114702/ which made some festivals and had great music by The Octopus Project...by far the most original, creative piece I have had the pleasure to work on.

Good luck getting IMDB to correct credits. I have fixes I have been waiting on for a couple years now...anyone had better luck?

Answer (score 1):

I only have one credit at the moment as a sound editor for this superhero film, *The Photon Effect* I worked on during my internship.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1037124/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2753455/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3678107/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2090162/

Answer (score 1):

Forever incomplete: http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2395008/